# VueJS/VueX : display table when store state has been populated

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I'm trying to develop a single file component where i would like to fetch user cars from backend and display the all loaded cars in a table.

What is the best way to handle that ?

For the moment, i call a **store action** (getUserCars) from the `created()` hook, and then I try to listen any change on a state property of my store using a `watch` to be able to build my table in UI. But it doesn't work yet..

Could you please help me?

```
<script>
import { mapActions, mapGetters } from "vuex";

export default {
    created: function() {
        console.log("created() - called");
        this.getUserCars();
    },
    mounted: function() {
        console.log("mounted() - called");
    },
    destroyed: function() {
        console.log("destroyed() - called");
    },
    watch: {
        userSites(newValue, oldValue) {
            console.log(`watch() Updating from ${oldValue} to ${newValue}`);

            const options = {
                data: {type: "local", source: this.userCars(), pageSize: 5},
                layout: {theme: "default", class: "", scroll: !1, footer: !1},
                sortable: !0,
                pagination: !0,
                columns: [
                    {field: "name", title: "Name"},
                    {field: "createdAt", title: "Created At"}
                ]
            };
            $('#m_datatable').mDatatable(options);

        },
    },
    computed: {

    },
    methods: {
        ...mapGetters(["userCars"]),
        ...mapActions(["getUserCars"]),
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: I think you don't need watches. Did you try it with computed properties?

Comment: By default, Store state are also reactive. If state changes, it will update the UI. But action has to be inside computed properties.

Comment: @varit05 Ok, so where I need to put the code responsible to build the datatable ?

Comment: Is your UI directly interacting with Database, without any REST Api/Service?

Comment: No, first i get the list of cars using a REST API call and store them using a mutation in a state property. Then, i would like to automatically get the list of cars just loaded to create my datatable using the javascript code that i put in my description

Answer (score 1):

If your `getUserCars()` action in your store hydrates the state with the data, then you can have a getter like the `userCars` one I can see in your code. **You just have to move the mapGetters helper from methods to computed.**

Then you can access it in the template and do whatever you want.

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["userCars"])
},
methods: {
    ...mapActions(["getUserCars"])
}
```